# Evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}e^{\frac{1-x^{4}}{x^{2}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I was proving that the limit of a two-variable function does not exist and I came across computing $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}e^{\frac{1-x^{4}}{x^{2}}}$ and I am not sure how to approach it. Is it true that near $0$, I can ignore $x^{4}$ and argue that $\frac{1}{x^{2}}$ tends to infinity as $x\to0$ and therefore the limit is infinity?

Comment: $$\frac{1-x^4}{x^2} = \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{x^4}{x^2} = \frac{1}{x^2} - x^2$$

Comment: You can use $e^{\frac{(1-x^2)(1+x^2)}{x^2}} > e^{\frac{1-x^2}{x^2}} = e^{\frac1{x^2}}\cdot e^{-1}$

Comment: It's never correct to simply "ignore" terms without proper justification, but we can say that the limit $\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{1-x^4}{x^2}$ is of the form "$\frac{1}{0}$", and since the denominator is positive, it must equal $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

As $x \to 0$ clearly

$$e^{\frac{1-x^4}{x^2}} =e^{\left(\frac{1}{x^2} -1 \right) (1+x^2)} \to \infty$$

(Notice that the term in parentheses at the right approaches $1$ and the term  at the left get infinitely large as $x \to 0$)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$\frac{1-x^4}{x^2} = \frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{x^4}{x^2} = \frac{1}{x^2} - x^2$$ Now move the limit to the exponent of $e$ and you get $$e^{\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} - x^2}$$ and now since  $\frac{1}{x^2}\to \infty$ we can conclude that the limit is $\infty$